# EditText is not accepting Numeral input

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have started developing for Adroid Phones a couple of days ago and I have exported at last my first app to my Smartphone. Everything looks like the emulator but when I try to input numbers (1,2,3,4...) It doesn't work.

At first I thought maybe it was because of the inputType:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

But then I tried to remove it in order to have access to the whole keyboard. Normal keys work but still no number will be accepted.

This is how I declared the xml for the EditText.

```
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/poids"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="Entrez votre Poids"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />
```

Note: I run os 4.0.4 on my phone and I'm developing an app for 2.3.3 maybe the problem comes from there?

EditText Code:

```
    EditText poids= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.poids)
    ...
    poids.setOnKeyListener(modifListener1);
    ....
    private OnKeyListener modifListener1 = new OnKeyListener(){

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            result.setText(defaut);
            poids.getText().clear();
            return true;
        }

    };
```

Picture of App:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIxXy.png]

Comment: it is working for me, can you check your log trace to see what is going on.

Comment: Post code related to the EditText in question.  Do you have some sort of TextWatcher on it?

Comment: try using `android:inputType="numberSigned"`

Comment: Could it just be some sort of NumLock on the actual phone.  Have you recently tried inputting numbers in another app?

Comment: So, as for the log trace, I get this when I click on the field that pops up the keyboard:

`06-06 17:00:53.173: W/Settings(358): Cannot load auto correction threshold setting. currentAutoCorrectionSetting: 0, autoCorrectionThresholdValues: [, 0.22, 0.08, 0]`

After that when I push the numbers nothing happens. I'll try the other answers now :)

Comment: Regarding the "numberSigned" inputTpye, it gives me the same result. As for the numbers they are not blocked in other aps. When I remove the EditText inputType, I can use letters but still no numbers.

I'll edit my primary post with the code related to the listener I have on the EditText as well as a screenshot of the non working window.

Again thanks for the quick answers everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

It's here:

```
  public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        result.setText(defaut);
        poids.getText().clear();
        return true;
    }
```

I don't know why but this was blocking numbers from being entered in the Edit text. At first I had made that because when I emulated the phones, I couldn't delete the "hint".

I just tried to completely remove the two classes associated to the two  and it was all good.

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is not accepting numeral input?

For Some reason the emulator won't except any input values from the numeric key's on your keyboard try using the numeric keys on top of your keyboard, the one's with `(!@#)` symbols and it works.